# How to create a library in eclipse and use in a project

Tags: eclipse, maven

i have a Maven Dependencies library i want to use it in another project , so is there a way to save it (i don't know where) as a public library and to import it in the project.

Any idea will be appreciated :))

Comment: Could you be more accurate please ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are saying, you just want to use a library ? It seems to obvious, or you are a real newcomer to Maven :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are developping your own one, you just have to run mvn install to compile, package it and "save" it in your repository.

In either case, you should read this great (and free !) book : http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book .

If I'm mistaken, please try to rephrase or explain what you really want.

Comment: you're totally right but i have a problem with maven it downloads jars declared in the pom so i can find them in the .m2/repository... but i can't see them in the project . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473889/maven-is-not-downloading-jars#comment15151953_11473889

Answer (score 1):

i found this http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-create-an-eclipse-user-library-for-the-tomcat-jar-files.html it's useful but i wanted to import an existing library